# Oracle apex- update item value on server when selecting in client

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have 'select list' item (P193_ROTOR), and I need the value that is currently selected to be used in another item (P193_MAX).

Select list Item:

[image: Select list item]

Dependent item:

[image: Dependent item]

I created dynamic action on selecting the 'P193_ROTOR' that the 'P193_MAX' will be refreshed.
The problem is the 'P193_MAX' is getting the previous selected value of 'P193_ROTOR' and not the current.
So it means that the selected value of 'P193_ROTOR' is not being updated on the server, how do I do this?

I must note that I need the value on server side, so Javascript code won't help me here.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you put P193_ROTOR in "items to submit" of the action in your dynamic action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a dynamic action with this options:

**EVENT**: change

**Selection Type**: P193_ROTOR

[image]

now in true section add Action Execute PL/SQL Code

**PL/SQL Code**: :P193_MAX := :P193_ROTOR;

**Items to Submit**: P193_ROTOR

**Items to Return**: P193_MAX

[image]